# How can I split text on commas not within double quotes, while keeping the quotes?

Tags: javascript

So I'm trying to split a string in javacript, something that looks like this:

```
"foo","super,foo"
```

Now, if I use `.split(",")` it will turn the string into an array containing `[0]"foo" [1]"super [2]foo"`
however, I only want to split a comma that is between quotes, and if I use `.split('","')`, it will turn into `[0]"foo [1]super,foo"`

Is there a way I can split an element expressing delimiters, but have it keep certain delimiters WITHOUT having to write code to concatenate a value back onto the string?

EDIT:

I'm looking to get `[0]"foo",[1]"super,foo"` as my result. Essentially, the way I need to edit certain data, I need what is in [0] to never get changed, but the contents of [1] will get changed depending on what it contains. It will get concatenated back to look like `"foo", "I WAS CHANGED"` or it will indeed stay the same if the contents of [1] where not something that required a change

Comment: What's the final result you want from `"foo","super,foo"`?

Comment: Yes, thanks for the reminder to add it, Tom

Comment: sorry, you want the output the same as the input?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try this:

```
'"foo","super,foo"'.replace('","', '"",""').split('","');
```

Answer (score 2):

For the sake of discussion and benefit of everyone finding this page is search of help, here is a more flexible solution:

```
var text = '"foo","super,foo"';
console.log(text.match(/"[^"]+"/g));
```

outputs

```
['"foo"', '"super,foo"']
```

This works by passing the 'g' (global) flag to the RegExp instance causing match to return an array of all occurrences of `/"[^"]"/` which catches `"foo,bar"`, `"foo"`, and even `"['foo', 'bar']"` (`"["foo", "bar"]"` returns `[""["", "", "", ""]""]`.)